# Is reading from multiple shards required to process all data in the AWS Kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I'm processing records from a Kinesis stream with the Python's boto3 client, and every documentation I've been able to find only reads from the first shard. The code usually looks like this:

```py
response = self.kinesis_client.get_shard_iterator(
    StreamName=self.name,
    ShardId=self.details["Shards"][0]["ShardId"], # <-- this
    ShardIteratorType="LATEST",
)
shard_iter = response["ShardIterator"]
while True:
    response = self.kinesis_client.get_records(
        ShardIterator=shard_iter, Limit=10
    )
    process_records(response["Records"])
    try:
        shard_iter = response["NextShardIterator"]
    except KeyError:
        break
```

But in my case, there are 15 shards in the stream, configured by someone else, and the goal is for this consumer to read ALL the messages in the stream. When I read just from the 1st shard, the `get_records()` call returns a response without the `NextShardIterator` so I'm guessing I have to pull from multiple shards. Is that assumption correct?

What would be the best practice here? Creating a thread for each of the shards and reading them in parallel? The processing is fast enough to process everything in that stream.

Comment: Yes, you need to read each shard individually. You may also need to handle a reshard (when the `get_records()` call returns information about child shards). Multi-threading is probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Can you point me to some docs, or write about reshards? Because I've noticed I sometimes get information about child shards and don't know what to do with it. For multithreading - are you suggesting that looping get_records() over all the shards would be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is reading from multiple shards required to process all data in the AWS Kinesis stream?

TL;DR: yes.

Kinesis is a durable event streaming solution. The state of its events (whether they are processed or not) is separated from their data. The data is immutable, and the state is not a concern of Kinesis at all. This allows having multiple independent subscribers to each stream.

Once Kinesis has ingested your events, it doesn't know (or care) whether or not you have processed them, or if are you going process them again. A Kinesis stream stores the records for the duration of the stream's retention period (24 hours by default, but can be extended to up to a year). There's a pretty strong guarantee that once you have received a response that the record is there, it's there (i.e. can be eventually read within the retention period). The records have an intrinsic order: if a record B comes after A, all the readers will get B after A. You can even introduce strong ordering of the records on the client side by putting them into a causal relationship: in a loop, take the sequential number from the response for a previous record, and use it as `SequenceNumberForOrdering` for the next one.

These kinds of guarantees come at a price (both monetary and computational), that's why Kinesis streams are broken into shards. Each shard has its own throughput limits, and you pay for every shard separately. The serialization guarantee also only applies to records within a single shard.

To balance between the cost and the throughput, Kinesis allows dynamically changing the number of active shards within a single stream without having to change your producer settings. As far as the producer is concerned, it just needs to send `PutRecord` requests to a particular stream. The stream will distribute them among the shards automatically.

To do this seamlessly, without stopping the stream, while preserving the ordering, Kinesis supports [resharding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-using-sdk-java-resharding.html): it changes the number of shards by doing the operations known as shard splitting and shard merging. Both these operations make the stream stop writing to the old shard(s), mark them as closed, and start writing to the new shard(s). The fact of split or merge is also persisted, and all the records in the child shards are considered to have happened after all the records in the parent shards. It is particularly important for the shard merges: you should not start processing the records in the child shard until you have processed all the records in both parent shards.

Since Kinesis doesn't track the event status, it becomes the client responsibility: your processor should keep track of the progress ("checkpoints") through each shard, as well as of the splits and merges. It's not too hard, but not completely trivial either.

AWS provides a library called [KCL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/shared-throughput-kcl-consumers.html) (Kinesis Client Library) which does it for you. Unfortunately, it's only available in Java and has a hard dependency on DynamoDB as a store for the processing state. It may invoke subprocesses written in other languages.

> What would be the best practice here? Creating a thread for each of the shards and reading them in parallel? The processing is fast enough to process everything in that stream.

That's one way to do that, however, you should mind splits and merges and rebalance your threads accordingly.

If you use KCL, it will balance the mappings ("leases") between shards and workers automatically.

Comment: Reading the docs, I'm not sure if resharding happens automatically, triggered by some internal Kinesis operation, or does it only happen when triggered manually by calling the API? In other words, can I ignore resharding if I'm sure no-one will trigger it from the API?

Comment: @IvanVoras: if your using on-demand capacity mode, it reshards automatically. If you're using provisioning capacity mode, and change the number of shards from the console or terraform, it reshards as well. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "ignoring" the resharding. If you're rolling your own consumer, you'll need to track the progress through many shards one way or another. You mentioned that you do get information about child shards, it means that resharding does happen on your stream.

Comment: Thanks, this clears much of the questions I had! One last question: do you know if a loop that calls `describe_stream()` to get a list of shards, then loops through all of them with `get_records()` good enough to ensure reshard events are handled properly?

Comment: The exact sequence I'm proposing is: `describe_stream()` -> loop through shards -> `get_shard_iterator()` for each shard -> `get_records()` called only once for the iterator

Comment: @IvanVoras: are you going to reprocess the whole stream each run time you run your consumer application?

Comment: Why would that happen, if I'm calling `get_shard_iterator()` with `ShardIteratorType='LATEST'`? I'd expect that the danger is that I'd drop records, not reprocess them? I saw the part of your answer "your processor should keep track of the progress ("checkpoints") through each shard, as well as of the splits and merges. It's not too hard, but not completely trivial either.", but without documentation to follow and see how Kinesis expects me to do it, and if the boto3 client doesn't to it for me, it's too little information to go on.

Comment: @IvanVoras: with latest, you will only get the records that were inserted after you started the application, so yes, if your application dies, you have a chance to lose records inserted while it was restarting. How to checkpoint a Kinesis stream is too long for comments but would make a great new question. Ask it!

Comment: @IvanVoras: also, the whole selling point of Kinesis is multiple consumers and the ability to replay events. If you don't need any if that, SQS would be much easier and much cheaper.

Comment: Yes, SQS would be much better for this purpose but I can't change that. I'm posting a new question.

Comment: @IvanVoras: you can create an EventBridge pipe and target SQS (or, if your processor has HTTP API for push-based workflow, you can target its HTTP endpoint directly). A pipe processor with a Kinesis stream as a source is a KCL daemon in thin disguise, running on AWS servers.